# Change fill color of imported svg file

Tags: html, css, svg

Let say I'm using a SVG file as an icon. A complex drawing, with an outer border

```
<svg x="0" y="0"
  width="425.197px" height="425.197px" viewBox="0 0 425.197 425.197">
    <image id="logo" x="0" y="0" width="425.197px" height="425.197px" xlink:href="logo.svg"/>
    <image id="border" x="0" y="0" width="425.197px" height="425.197px" xlink:href="logo-border.svg"/>
</svg>
```

I can easily hide the border on hover:

```
svg:hover image#border {
    display: none;
}
```

But I'm not able to change the fill color:

```
svg:hover image#logo {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Is there a way or should I change my import method (using object, iframe, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the hover logic in the image file itself where it would look like this...

```
#logo {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And then **also** change from an `<image>` to either and `<iframe>` or `<object>` as `<image>` tags don't receive pointer events.

Basically if you imagine what bitmap images are capable of then SVG images are capable of the same things. Since png or gif images aren't interactive, neither are SVG images so that your mental map of what an image is capable of is not compromised.

Comment: Yeah I can do that, thank you. But in this way I cannot use `:hover`, or I don't manage to.

Comment: I've done a test. If you open this svg file: ([http://muxisar.at/pics/PA93G.svg](http://muxisar.at/pics/PA93G.svg)), you'll see that background change on hover. Not anymore when the [file is included using `<svg>`](http://muxisar.at/pics/).

Comment: Here's an example of a `:hover` rule inside an svg file: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/hover-change-fill.svg

Comment: It also works alone but not when embedded (here is another test: [http://muxisar.at/pics/1/](http://muxisar.at/pics/1/)). Or maybe I should embed it using another method than `<svg><image/></svg>` ?

Comment: Yes `<image>` will not work. See http://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/ for more details